# Background application with menu bar

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an application which I would like to hide from the dock. Therefore `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `YES`.

Still, I would like to show a window to the user and therefore I would like to show a menu bar and have the window shown in the task switcher (CMD+Tab). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such, no. That's part of the meaning of UIElement. It can show windows, but not have a menu bar nor an icon in the Dock or application switcher (which is run by the Dock).

You can transform a UIElement to a normal application using `-[NSApplication setActivationPolicy:]` but not back again.

Your UIElement could launch a helper application to present the GUI, which would then quit when it's done. That might achieve the effect you're looking for, but will of course be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this. It's not the apple way and just gets confusing.
I guess NSMenuItem would be a good way to solve this.